# Searching values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to search for a string value in column `ProductName` in `dataGridView1` then I want to delete or hide any other value in `dataGridView1`

Search value is typed in `textBox1`

I tried this

```
        string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                {
                    row.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
```

but I get object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: What have you tried? You should post your current code even if it's not working.

Comment: u mean you want to hide the other row where value not found..!!

Comment: btw, for showing the matching rows only, you could add the matching rows to a new datagridview2 and have it displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try, If I understand your problem.

```
string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        {
            row.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index); //Remove
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to manipulate your data(deleting rows, etc), you are going to have to bind your dataGridView to a DataTable or a DataSet and then manipulate your records through the DataSet/DataTable. This would let you reflect the changes in you dataGridView.